# Is it correct to say "Gathering all together, I'd like to say ..."

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

Let's say I wrote a lot of things that describes my point of view about something and now I want to summarize and I'd like to know if it's ok to say:

Gathering all together, I'd like to say...

Comment: It doesn't really work, because you're not really gathering them together -- you're summarizing them, and a summary is an abbreviated form. A better phrase would be, "To sum it all up..."